# The controller with the name 'NewController' is not registered

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I have two controllers 
**NewController :**

```
     var myApp = angular.module('myApp');

    myApp.controller('NewController', ['$scope', '$http', '$location', '$routeParams', function ($scope, $http, $location, $routeParams) {
        console.log('NewController loaded..');
}]);
```

**OldController:**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp');

        myApp.controller('OldController', ['$scope', '$http', '$location', '$routeParams', function ($scope, $http, $location, $routeParams) {
            console.log('Old Controller loaded..');
    }]);
```

**App.js**

```
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['ngRoute']);

    myApp.config(function($routeProvider,$locationProvider){
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
        $routeProvider
        .when('/products/add-new-product',{
            controller: 'OldController',
            templateUrl: 'views/product/add-new-product.html'
        })
           .when('/merchant/view-posted-products',{
                controller: 'NewController',
                templateUrl: 'views/dashboard/view-posted-products.html'
            })
            .otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/home'
            })
    });
```

**Problem is:** All my routes with **OldController** are working, but for **NewController** I am getting error , **The controller with the name 'NewController' is not registered.** 
Please help..

Comment: did you included the `NewController` js file in your app?

Comment: @Hadi :How to inject `NewController` ?

Comment: sorry, I mean including js file after `app.js`

Comment: How to include js file? I have both the controllers in my directory .

Comment: How included `app.js` or `OldController.js`? so similar to same way include `NewController`

Comment: My bad forgot to add `NewController`, Thanks